# Tikz Diagram - Macro Help

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have some code for a network diagram that works when I use it in the body. I've been trying to define a macro so I don't have to write this repeatedly. I have named tikz coordinates defined directly above this macro. `nodeFrom` and `nodeTo` are already defined coordinates. `senderText`, `receiverText`and `arrowText` comments above the arrows.

```
% originally from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/macros/
% draw arrow from sender to receiver
% syntax: \senderarrow[nodeFrom, senderText, arrowText, nodeTo, receiverText]
\newcommand{\senderarrow}[5]{
\draw (#1) node[left]{\begin{tabular}{r}
% \textit{active close}\\
\verb$#2$
\end{tabular}};
\draw (#4) node[right]{\begin{tabular}{l}
\verb${#5}$
\end{tabular}};
\draw[->] (#1) -- (#4) node[midway,sloped,above]{\verb${#3}$};
}
% draw arrow from receiver to sender
% syntax: \receiverarrow{nodeFrom, receiverText, arrowText, nodeTo, senderText}
\newcommand{\receiverarrow}[5]{
\draw ({#1}) node[right]{\begin{tabular}{r}
% \textit{active close}\\
\verb$#2$
\end{tabular}};
\draw (#4) node[left]{\begin{tabular}{l}
\verb${#5}$
\end{tabular}};
\draw[->] (#1) -- (#4) node[midway,sloped,above]{\verb${#3}$};
}
```

Directly below this definition I tried:

```
\senderarrow{E}{pkt0 sent}{pkt0}{F}{pkt0 received, delivered, ACK0 sent}
```

This was the error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $. <template> \unskip } \hskip \tabcolsep\endtemplate 
l.193 ...}{F}{pkt0 received, delivered, ACK0 sent}
```

I'm not quite sure why this is happening. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: I didn't write this code originally; I've been changing someone else's for my own purposes. If there are other errors or problems please tell me so I can fix them!

Comment: You cannot have `\verb` inside of macro definitions.  Perhaps a `\texttt{#2}` or a `\detokenize{#2}` would work, depending on the structure allowed in those arguments and the font desired..

Comment: You need to enclose the content of `\verb` between exclamation marks, like `\verb!<here>!` but even then, I'm not sure it's the best thing to do here. Why are you using `\verb`? Besides, your code shows other errors too.

Comment: First lesson on writing macros: document the arguments.  Is #1 a coordinate name or a x,y pair?  Even you might forget eventually.

Comment: @Alenanno I was using \verb because it was a short inline comment. Are there other errors? I've never used tikz before for something like this so I appreciate if you could point them out.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes replacing `\verb` with `\texttt` worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP indicates that my comment "worked perfectly", I will convert the comment into an answer.  Without a full MWE to work with, I am unable to actually run any code.  But I noticed that the OP developed a macro with several instances of `\verb` therein.  A number of comments around this site will note that `\verb` cannot appear inside of a macro.

I noted from the OP's usage context, however, that none of the arguments to be processed appeared to actually contain special verbatim characters like `%`, `\`, `#`, `$`, etc.  Thus, on the assumption that what the OP really desired was a teletype-style (tt) font, I suggested to replace instances of `\verb$...$` with `\texttt{...}`.  Apparently, this was sufficient to meet the needs of the OP.